# Unexplainable Null Reference Exception behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception

| **Framework**: .NET Framework 4.5.2 |
**OS**: Windows 10 |
**IDE**: Visual Studio |

---

I have 4 lines of code in the middle of a C# function.

```
Hashtable A = new Hashtable();    
Hashtable B = new Hashtable();
int C = 0;
string D = "";
```

On launching the code in a debugger in Visual Studio, I get an unusual error on the forth line:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

What is even more stranger is that if I were to remove the line where string D is declared/initialized, the error now shifts to the line above for variable C. The error keeps on shifting to the line before If I now were to remove the lines for variable C then B and eventually A.

**What I have already tried.**

1. I tried to replace the string declaration with String.Empty, it still gave the error.
2. Tried declaring and initializing the variable in separate lines, still got the error.

**What I need help on?**

1. Are there any hard limits on the number of variables you can declare in a C# function ?
2. How to go by solving this issue ! (Of Course)

### Edits

I am limited to sharing the screenshot of the part of the code, not the whole function.
[image]

Comment: Could you post the whole function? Also, the whole error?

Comment: @OP I think with more information about the enviroment (are there maybe interceptors etc.) Noone can help you. I'm quite sure that `string D = "";` by itsself will NEVER cause a runtime error.

Comment: The debugger sometimes displays execeptions at wrong locations. Especially when build optimazations are turned on. None of the lines displayed here can cause a NullReferenceException

Comment: Read the duplicate and debug your code to find out what's going on. It's not `string D = "";`. If that was the case, nobody would be able to use strings. Where is the exception thrown? What is the *actual, full* exception text? An exception includes the file name and line where it was thrown, and the stack trace that led to it. Where is the exception actually thrown?

Comment: Follow the call stack or paste it here to review. These declarations won't throw the error.

Comment: I suggest rearranging the lines to see if the error follows one of them. You can also comment out some lines to see it it goes away. Also, dig into the Hashtable constructor.

Comment: Just uploaded the Error Screenshot.

Comment: @Panagiotis, I have gone through similar questions for NullReferenceException. None relate to what I asked.

Comment: `overallHRAScoreCurrent` - is it null?

Comment: I see this question was closed because someone felt it already has an answer in another question posted before. I have been stuck on this for a complete day now, and I had already gone through that question before. Can that "Someone" tell me where in that linked question the answer is ?

Comment: @Fildor, Its not, I hovered over it in Visual Studio, it has a value and so does other variables.

Comment: @DilnoorSingh: the duplicate question doesn't tell exactly the answer to your question. But it gives you all tools necessary to find the reason of the error yourself. Also, sometimes it helps to simply rebuild the solution to see the real line that caused the exception.

Comment: @DilnoorSingh post *the exception text*, not screenshots of your debugger. That image proves nothing at all, especially if the exception was thrown in a different line. Click on `View Details` to see the full exception details. Click on `Copy Details` to copy the full text and post it in your question. `

Comment: I did try to rebuild the solution to no avail. But I was to solve the problem based on @derpirscher comment before. The NullReferenceException was actually coming from somewhere else. Thanks.

Comment: For anyone bumping into this question in the future, based on @derpirscher suggestions. I turned off Code Optimizations by going to Project Properties > Build > Optimize Code. Relaunched the project and discovered that the line underneath the string declaration(not shown in the screenshot) was legitimately throwing the NullReferenceException error. Fixed it.